# The HOST shortcut keys are not working in GUEST windows in VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, i3-window-manager

I am using `i3wm` as my Windows manager in my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and VirtualBox version 5.2.18. I want to change the workspaces using the i3 shortcuts like **ALT+some_number** to go to that number workspace. When I am in my Guest workspace, that shortcut simply doesn't work and I have to move my mouse cursor to change my Workspace.

Comment: Is Ubuntu the guest OS?

Comment: No, guest OS is MS DOS 6.22!